# How to write user mode virtual audio device driver in vista?

Tags: windows, audio

How to write user mode virtual audio device driver in vista? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: the DDK has an example driver. Also you could do a directshow audio capture source ex: https://github.com/rdp/virtual-audio-capture-grabber-device